# jqgrid - how to retrieve value from userdata

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a grid where one of the column will be total up and this total is display on the footer. I manage to done that with:

```
    $response->userdata['no'] = 'Total:';
    $response->userdata['amount'] = $total_amount;
```

When user want to add a record, I need to check that the value entered by the user for the Amount field is not more than 100.

For example, lets say now the grid table has 2 record rows. The Amount for record 1 is 30 and the Amount for record 2 is 50. So the Total is 80. Lets say user now call up the add form and key in 40 for the Amount to add. When the Submit button is click, error message should be prompt and the record will not be added because the Total exceeded 100 if user want to add 40.

User cannot Submit until the Total is <= 100.

My question is, how to retrieve the Total value and do the checking so that the Total will not exceed 100?

Thanks.

Alex

EDIT:

```
var table_grid = jQuery("#my_table");

table_grid.jqGrid({
    url:'get.php',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    async: false,
    colNames:['No','Amount'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'no',index:'no',width:50,sortable:false,editable:false,editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10}},
        {name:'amount',index:'amount',align:'right',width:100,sortable:true,editable:true,formatter:'number'}
    ],
    footerrow : true,
    userDataOnFooter : true
});
```

Comment: Can you post the grid code also?

Comment: I have added the codes of the grid. I hope that is what you are referring to. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. We can retrieve user data with this:

```
userdata = (jQuery("#my_table").getUserData());
```

To access the value, we just do this:

```
userdata.amount;
```

I hope this will help someone.